# Selecting certain <tr> tag with JSoup

Tags: java, html, select, jsoup

I am new to JSoup and have been working with it for a few days now with no problems, until I came across this one. I'm trying to get all the `<tr>` tags from a table where the `<tr>`s have a child `<td>` tag with a certain class.

I am trying to retrieve the data from [this website](http://www.valgrande-pajares.com/parte-de-nieve-pajares.htm), this is what I'm trying:

```
document.select("#partedenieve tr:has(td.zonas)");
```

I don't know if it works because the problem here is that if you select just `#partedenieve tr` it only returns the `<tr>`s on the `thead`. I've tried some other queries, but when I finally achieve to get `<tr>`s from the tbody it won't return all the `<tr>` tags either.

I don't know if this problem may be related to the rowspan tag present on the `<tr>`s I want to get... but I've had no luck so far.

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Elements elts = document.select("tr > td.class");
```

This will return all td elements with the given class. So you just have to get each unique parent:

```
List<Element> list = new ArrayList<Element>();
for (Element elt : elts) {
    if (!list.contains(elt) {
        list.add(elt);
    }
}
```

Now, your `list` object contains all of your tr elements.